# How to determine the state of peer access without producing a warning in cuda-memcheck

Tags: cuda

In a multi-gpu system, I use the return value of
`cudaError_t cudaDeviceDisablePeerAccess ( int  peerDevice )` to determine if peer access is disabled. In that case, the function returns `cudaErrorPeerAccessNotEnabled`

This is not an error in my program, but produces a warning in both cuda-gdb and cuda-memcheck since an API call did not return cudaSuccess.

In the same manner `cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess` returns `cudaErrorPeerAccessAlreadyEnabled` if access has already been enabled.

How can one find out if peer access is enabled / disabled without producing a warning?

Comment: 1. I don't believe it is possible using the CUDA runtime API.  2. You can always file a bug at developer.nvidia.com requesting desired behavior  3. Since at the start of your process, all devices are initially in a disabled peer state, you should be able to work around this by keeping track of what you have done to each device, e.g. in a separate global array.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing comments into an answer: you can't.

The runtime API isn't blessed with the ability to have informational/warning level status returns *and* error returns. Everything which isn't success is treated as an error. And the toolchain utilities like `cuda-memcheck` cannot be instructed to ignore errors. The default beahaviour is to report and continue, so it will not interfere with anything, but it will emit an error message.

If you want to avoid the errors then you will need to build some layers of your own state tracking and condition preemption to avoid potential errors being returned.